# How to set custom session timeout for cherrypy at runtime

Tags: session, cherrypy, session-timeout

Need custom session timeout which can be configured at runtime after the session is created for user.

In my application I needed custom session timeout depending on the type of user. eg. For admin users the timeout will be 30mins, for normal users the timeout will be 15mins. The urls are the same for both of the users, so can not be configured in application configuration.

Comment: So I figured out a workaround for this. I wrote a tool which will do the following. 

```
def set_custom_timeout():
admin_user = self.check_admin_user()
 if admin_user:
           cookies = cherrypy.serving.response.cookie
            cookie_name = "session_id"
            cookies[cookie_name]['max-age'] = 21600 # 6 hours
            expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
            cookies[cookie_name]['expires'] = expires.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
```

Comment: This tool can be configured at application configuration like below
'/' : {
.
.
'tools.set_custom_timeout.on': True,
}

Comment: Here is an article I wrote about this solution https://medium.com/@lokeshpathrabe/server-polling-with-session-timeout-40727b30f86f